# Form data changes over devices synchronously

Tags: angular

I'm coding a test application on angular2. The weird thing happens when I run the app on the wifi local network over my tablet.
When I click on links (which clearly made by angular routers) on PC to load another component, the change also happens on the tablet. This is synchronized in every action I take between tablet and PC, like typing in inputs.
Can anyone explain why such such thing happens? or is this a feature that I just don't know about? or any additional info about this situation?

Comment: I updated my answer and provided a link. You can check your package.json file to find out what tools you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a angular 2 feature. What tools are you using to build/host your project? If you are using [browser-sync](https://www.browsersync.io/), it uses sockets to keep your browsers in sync.
According to your comment. you use browser-sync. And it cause syncing your app over the browsers.

Comment: I'm using lite server. and yes it's because of the browser sync. you mentioned.